# Asp.Versioning.Http AmbiguousMatchException: The request matched multiple endpoints on controllers

Tags: api, controller, asp.net-web-api-routing, api-versioning, aspnet-api-versioning

I am trying to achieve header based versioning on my controllers with Asp.Versioning.Http package version 6.4.0
it is supposed to be super simple [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnet-api-versioning/wiki/Versioning-by-Header#aspnet-core-with-mvc-core) however i get `AmbiguousMatchException: The request matched multiple endpoints` exception

Here is my Program class

and my controllers defined like that:

```
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
    // Add services to the container.
    builder.Services.AddControllers();

    // Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
    builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
    builder.Services.AddApiVersioning(options => {
       // options.ApiVersionReader = new HeaderApiVersionReader("api-version");
        options.DefaultApiVersion = new ApiVersion(1.0);
        options.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true;
        options.ReportApiVersions = true;
    }).EnableApiVersionBinding();
    builder.Services.AddMvc();
    builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

    var app = builder.Build();

    // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
       // app.UseSwagger();
        //app.UseSwaggerUI();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseAuthorization();
    app.MapHealthChecks("/health/live");
    app.MapControllers();
    app.Run();
```

```
   namespace Things.Service.Controllers.V1
   {
    [ApiController]
    [ApiConventionType(typeof(DefaultApiConventions))]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    [Asp.Versioning.ApiVersion(1.0)]
    public class ThingsController : ControllerBase
    {
       // controller logic
    }
   }
```

```
    namespace Things.Service.Controllers.V2
    {
    [ApiController]
    [ApiConventionType(typeof(DefaultApiConventions))]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    [Asp.Versioning.ApiVersion(2.0)]`your text`
    public class ThingsController : ControllerBase
     {
       // controller logic
     }
    }
```

I get this exception:

```
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.AmbiguousMatchException: The request matched multiple    endpoints. Matches: 

Things.Service.Controllers.V2.ThingsController.GetAllAsync (Things.Service)
Things.Service.Controllers.V1.ThingsController.GetAllAsync (Things.Service)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is happening because you are missing `AddMvc`. Don't let the name fool you, this adds MVC Core, not the full MVC stack. Starting in `6.0`, the new setup pivots on `IApiVersioningBuilder` so that all of the setup is in one place and, hopefully, easier to follow. If you're coming from earlier versions (e.g. <= `5.x`), this might be a surprise. This change was necessary because `AddApiVersioning` is now the foundation for *Minimal APIs*, which doesn't include MVC Core or controller support. `AddMvc` adds those features.

```cs
         
services
 .AddApiVersioning()     // Asp.Versioning.Http : Core services and Minimal APIs
 .AddMvc()               // Asp.Versioning.Mvc : MVC Core
 .AddApiExplorer()       // Asp.Versioning.Mvc.ApiExplorer : API Explorer
 .AddOData()             // Asp.Versioning.OData : OData support
 .AddODataApiExplorer(); // Asp.Versioning.OData.ApiExplorer : OData API Explorer
```

Since you're using MVC Core and controllers, you do not need `EnableApiVersionBinding`. MVC Core has support for *Model Binders*. `AddMvc` will register all those services. If you want to receive the incoming `ApiVersion` in your controller action, you need only add a parameter of type `ApiVersion` with the name of your choice. For example:

```cs
namespace Things.Service.Controllers.V1
{
   [ApiVersion(1.0)]
   [ApiController]
   [ApiConventionType(typeof(DefaultApiConventions))]
   [Route("[controller]")]
   public class ThingsController : ControllerBase
   {
      [HttpGet]
      public IActionResult Get(ApiVersion version) => Ok();
   }
}
```

*Minimal APIs* do not have a way to support this type of model binding. `EnableApiVersionBinding` provides a way to make it work. It won't hurt anything if you've added it, but it's unnecessary.

Finally, it looks like you have included a version number in your namespaces. If this is indeed your setup, you might consider using the `VersionByNamespaceConvention`. This would negate the need to decorate controllers with `[ApiVersion]`. The API version would be derived from the namespace itself. For additional details, see the [Version By Namespace Convention](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnet-api-versioning/wiki/API-Version-Conventions#version-by-namespace-convention) documentation.

Comment: I have this line `builder.Services.AddMvc(); ` right after `builder.Services.AddApiVersioning`.  In my version of the package  6.4.0, i cannot chain the methods as you showed because `builder.Services.AddApiVersioning` returns IApiVersioningBuilder which doesnt have those extensions. AddApiExplorer() is not available. I need to keep targeting Core 6.0, is there any way to make it work with the current version?

Comment: Those extension methods are not available because you must not be using `Asp.Versioning.Mvc`, which contains the support for MVC Core. I've updated the answer with the mapping of package-to-extension method. .NET 6 is supported for all of these