# ASP.NET Core MVC API versioning by URL segment with Asp.Versioning.Mvc

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, aspnet-api-versioning

I try to versioning ASP.NET Core MVC API with [Asp.Versioning.Mvc](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Asp.Versioning.Mvc).

I create a new project like :

```bash
dotnet new webapi --framework net7.0
dotnet add package Asp.Versioning.Mvc --version 7.0.1
```

Next, I remove all controllers and edit **Program.cs** like :

```cs
using Asp.Versioning;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder.Services.AddApiVersioning();


var app = builder.Build();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();


app.Run();


[ApiVersion(1.0)]
[Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/helloworld")]
public class HelloWorldController : ControllerBase
{
    public string Get() => "Hello world! v1";
}

[ApiVersion(2.0)]
[Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/helloworld")]
public class HelloWorld2Controller : ControllerBase
{
    public string Get() => "Hello world! v2";
}
```

But when I start the API and call `http://localhost:5069/api/v1.0/helloworld`, I get this error :

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.AmbiguousMatchException: The request matched multiple endpoints. Matches: 

HelloWorldController.Get (ApiVersioningPoc)
HelloWorld2Controller.Get (ApiVersioningPoc)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DefaultEndpointSelector.ReportAmbiguity(CandidateState[] candidateState)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DefaultEndpointSelector.ProcessFinalCandidates(HttpContext httpContext, CandidateState[] candidateState)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DfaMatcher.MatchAsync(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

---

I found this similar question :

[Asp.Versioning.Http AmbiguousMatchException: The request matched multiple endpoints on controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75248836/asp-versioning-http-ambiguousmatchexception-the-request-matched-multiple-endpoi)

I try to add `AddMvc` (from the answer) without success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You definitely need `AddMvc()` after the `AddApiVersioning()` part because you are using `Controllers` instead of the Minimal APIs approach in this example.

After that you need to add the `[ApiController]` attribute to both of your Controllers like this:

```cs
[ApiVersion(1.0)]
[ApiController]
[Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/helloworld")]
public class HelloWorldController : ControllerBase
{
    public string Get() => "Hello world! v1";
}

[ApiVersion(2.0)]
[ApiController]
[Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/helloworld")]
public class HelloWorld2Controller : ControllerBase
{
    public string Get() => "Hello world! v2";
}
```

The library needs this attribute setup for all of your controller to work properly.

Comment: Sound like I miss `[ApiController]` on controllers. Thank.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that if you don't want apply the attribute to each controller **and** all of your controllers are API controllers, then you can apply the attribute to the assembly for all controllers just once. E.g. `[assembly: ApiController]`